# Proof Involving Hyperbolic Functions

Tags: polynomials, hypergeometric-function, hyperbolic-functions

> Find a sufficient condition on $p$, $q$ and $r$ for $p^2\cosh x+q^2 \sinh x=r^2$ to have at least one solution.

I know $\sinh x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$

and $\cosh x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$

Also $\ln(x)$ only has a solution when $x>0$.

Perhaps the discriminant will come into this as well, I'm not sure.

The answer is $r^4 \ge p^4 -q^4$, however, I am struggling to get to it.

Help would be much appreciated. Please don't use (too much) calculus if any in your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track

\begin{eqnarray}
p^2\cosh x + q^2\sinh x &=& r^2 \\
\frac{p^2}{2}(e^{x} + e^{-x}) + \frac{q^2}{2}(e^{x} - e^{-x}) &=& 2r^2 \\
(p^2 + q^2)e^x + (p^2 - q^2)e^{-x} &=& 2r^2 \\
(p^2 + q^2)e^{2x} + (p^2 - q^2) &=& 2r^2e^x
\end{eqnarray}

where in the last step I multiplied by $e^{x}$. Now call $y = e^x$, the equation above can be written as

$$
(p^2 + q^2)\color{blue}{y^2} - 2r^2 \color{blue}{y} + (p^2-q^2) = 0
$$

Which is a quadratic equation on $\color{blue}{y}$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

You are practically there with your question. Substitute for $ \cosh $ and $\sinh$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(p^2+q^2)(e^x)^2-2r^2e^x +(p^2-q^2)=0
\end{eqnarray*}
This is a quadratic in $e^x$ and we require that the discriminant is non negative. So
\begin{eqnarray*}
r^4 \geq (p^2+q^2)(p^2-q^2).
\end{eqnarray*}